# Linux socket read() can not read the response body correctly

Tags: c++, sockets, posix

```
int proxyRequest(string &request, char buffer[], struct hostent* host){
    int sockfd, sockopt;
    struct sockaddr_in their_addr;
    if((sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1){
        perror("Socket generating failed");
        return -1;
    }
    if(host==NULL){
        strcpy(buffer, "HTTP/1.1 404 Not found\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<h2>INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND</h2>");
    }
    else{
        their_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        their_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVERPORT);
        their_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = ((struct in_addr*)host->h_addr_list[0])->s_addr;
        if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&their_addr, sizeof(their_addr)) == -1){
            perror("Connection failed");
            return -1;
        }
        write(sockfd, request.c_str(), request.length());
        read(sockfd, buffer, BUFSIZE);
        cout << buffer << endl;
    }
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

I am making a simple proxy server and everything's fine, except I can't receive a correct resposne body.

[image]

This is the request that I send to server(www.example.com). This is represented as "request" in the code.

[image]

It seems that http headers are received correctly. However, the html file(body) is not sent at all. And there is a weird character instead of it. Why does this happen? Is it related to null character?

Comment: You should only output the number of characters that were read, not the entire buffer.

Comment: Remember that TCP sockets are streaming, a single `read` call may not receive all that was sent, you may need to loop until all is received.

Comment: With TCP, this: 'read(sockfd, buffer, BUFSIZE);', ie. ignoring the result retuned by read(), is an autoFail.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text, they are obnoxious.

Comment: Also `read` doesn't null terminate the buffer, so printing it as if it was a C-string (even assuming it contains text data) is highly illegal.

Comment: Read up on "short read/write" as well as EINTR. Real life is a bit more complicated than you seem to assume.

Comment: @nm I could read them OK, and I think the OP wanted to show us that funny character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, the html file(body) is not sent at all. And there is a weird character instead of it. Why does this happen?

The body *is* sent, but compressed. The following tells you that the content is compressed using the `gzip` algorithm:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

You'll need to either decompress it (taking care around NUL characters) or tell the server that you're not prepared to deal with `gzip` encoded content (i.e. remove the `Accept-Encoding` header in your request).

Comment: 'Binary' does not imply 'compressed'. 'Taking care around NUL characters' why?

Comment: Thanks, it works fine after I removed Accept-Encoding